# A code to add a role to all members of the server

Tags: discord, discord.js

```
const { MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js')

module.exports = {
  name: "addrole",
  aliases: ["role", "P!role"],
  category: "moderation",
  description: "Add role to any user",
  run: async (client, message, args) => {
   if (!message.member.hasPermission("MANAGE_ROLES")) {
      return message.channel.send("sorry you need permission to mute someone");
    }
    if (!message.guild.me.hasPermission("MANAGE_ROLES")) {
      return message.channel.send("I do not have the permissions");
    } 
    const targets = message.mentions.members;
    
    if(!targets.first()) return message.reply(`<:no:677902165859237894>please mention user!`)
    
    let arole = message.mentions.roles.first();
    
    if(!arole) return message.reply(`<:no:677902165859237894>please mention role for add!`)
    
    
      const embed = new MessageEmbed()
      
      .setColor("RANDOM")
      .setDescription(`<a:ok_:731369076315652167>role added ${arole}`)
      
      await message.channel.send(embed)
      
    targets.forEach(target => target.roles.add(arole));
    
  }
}
```

This adds role to the mentioned users.
Instead is there a way to alter

```
const targets = message.mentions.members
```

Such that the targets are all server members? And then by foreach, I can give the role to all the targets.

Answer (score 1):

You could access all guild members from `message.guild.members.cache` and use `.forEach()`.